# How do I restore my Ubuntu One account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, restore

I went into "Ubuntu One Preferences", then went under the "Devices" tab, then clicked the "Remove" button. I want to change my decision and restore my Ubuntu One account on this computer. I tried un-installing and re-installing Ubuntu One via the Ubuntu Software Center and that didn't seem to do anything. I am running Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit if that helps to know.

Thank you!

~ Tom

Answer (score 1):

Reregistering your computer with Ubuntu one should do the trick. I believe in 10.10 though you'll need to remove the token from your keyring manually.

To do this, go to  Applications > Accessories > Passwords and Encryption keys and look for the one with the name "Ubuntu One" and delete it. Next time you start up Ubuntu One Preferences you'll go through the setup again.